# MutationObserver class changes

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I am using `MutationObserver` to detect when a specific class has been added to an element.

```
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => { 
    mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
      const el = mutation.target;
      if ((!mutation.oldValue || !mutation.oldValue.match(/\bis-busy\b/)) 
        && mutation.target.classList 
        && mutation.target.classList.contains('is-busy')){
        alert('is-busy class added');
      }
    });
 });

observer.observe(document.querySelector('div'), { 
  attributes: true, 
  attributeOldValue: true, 
  attributeFilter: ['class'] 
});
```

My question is: **Is there a better way to verify that this is a newly added class?** Currently I am using regex to check that the class didn't exist previously and `classList` to check that the class exists now. Seems messy

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s53o8dLe/12/)

Comment: There's no other method but you can use regex for both checks for uniformity :-)

Answer (score 17):

@sliptype - You could do it in the below manner:

```
const element = document.querySelector('div');
let prevState = element.classList.contains('is-busy');
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => { 
    mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        const { target } = mutation;

        if (mutation.attributeName === 'class') {
            const currentState = mutation.target.classList.contains('is-busy');
            if (prevState !== currentState) {
                prevState = currentState;
                console.log(`'is-busy' class ${currentState ? 'added' : 'removed'}`);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try accessing `classname` on the target?

```
let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
        if (mutationRecord.target.className === "is-busy") {
            console.log("Class added....")

        } else {
            console.log("Class not added....")
        };
    })
});

let target = document.querySelector("your-div");

// MDN documentation
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe#attributefilter
observer.observe(target, {
 attributes : true,
 attributeFilter : ['style', 'class']
});
```

Comment: Would this be accurate if the class `is-busy` is already on there when a new change comes in, such as a different class being removed?

Comment: I guess it should be 'class' not 'className' in the `attributeFilter` array. No?

Comment: @KhairulAnik yes, that must be "class".

Comment: @KhairulAnik It's class in `attributeFilter` and className when traversing `target`

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution that Reena provided didn't work but I liked the solution. I had an error `S2339: Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'Node'.`

The solution was to save target as HTMLElement

```
let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
        const targetElement = mutationRecord.target as HTMLElement;
        if (targetElement.className === "is-busy") {
            console.log("Class added....")

        } else {
            console.log("Class not added....")
        };
    })
});
```