# How can I count the number of times a class of my html element changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I have 3 elements of the type div that makes a carousel with bootstrap. Each of these divs have a default class called 'item' and when the div is selected or visible it also has the class 'active'.

What I want to do is count how many times each of the items were visible (or in other words, had the `active` class). How would I go about doing that?

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div runat="server" id="CarouselHtml" class="carousel-inner" style="height: 500px;">
        Here the code of the slides is generated with the class item               
    </div>

    <a href="#carousel" ID="tagLeft" onclick="waitchange();" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a  href="#carousel" ID="tagR" class="right carousel-control" onclick="waitchange();"; data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

The html code that are the divs with the item classes are generated by C#

Comment: increment a global variable in the function that makes the change?  if you can't, add a wrapper function and have that be called in place of the existing functuion

Comment: Perhps you want to chek out MutationObserver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201984/mutationobserver-class-changes

Comment: @DaveS Bootstrap makes the change from the active class to the selected one, I do not realize it.

Comment: The most sensible way would be with a callback in whatever library you use for the carousel. I would suggest adding that bit of information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing should be handled by hooking into the controller for the carousel. But, in case that's not possible, you can use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
$(window).on('load', () => {
  const item = $('#item');
  let lastClassName = item.attr('class');
  let timesChanged = 0;

  const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    console.log('mutation occured');

    const currentClassName = item.attr('class');

    if (currentClassName === 'active' && lastClassName === 'item') {
      timesChanged = timesChanged + 1;
    }
    
    console.log(`times-changed: ${timesChanged}`);

    lastClassName = currentClassName;
  });
  mutationObserver.observe(
    item.get(0), 
    {
      attributes: true,
    },
  );
  
  window.setInterval(
    () => {
      const currentClassName = item.attr('class');

      if (currentClassName === 'item') {
        item.attr('class', 'active');
      } else {
        item.attr('class', 'item');
      }
    }, 
    5000
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div runat="server" id="CarouselHtml" class="carousel-inner" style="height: 500px;">
  </div>
  <div id="item" class="item"
                <a href="#carousel" ID="tagLeft" onclick="waitchange();" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>
                <a  href="#carousel" ID="tagR" class="right carousel-control" onclick="waitchange();";  data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ></span>
                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
```