# Change the style of an element when another element has class dynamically applied

Tags: javascript, triggers, element

I have a rollover menu that has a class applied to `<li>` elements on hover, which toggles the visibility of a div inside it.

The class is called "cbp-hropen" and is applied when the `<li>` is hovered.

I'd like to trigger the visibility of another completely separate element called "menuDimmer" when this class is applied to the `<li>`.

```
<div class="menuDimmer"></div>
<div id="menu" class="main">
<ul>
    <li>
        MENU
        <div class="cbp-hrsub">content...</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        MENU 2
        <div class="cbp-hrsub">content...</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So I'd like something similar to:

```
if ($("li").hasClass('cbp-hropen')) {
    $(".menuDimmer").fadeIn(100);
} else {
    $('.menuDimmer').fadeOut(100);
}
```

(sorry, I know that code is poor but just trying to get the message across)

This has to work dynamically, rather than on page load, as the trigger element itself is only active on hover.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event to add the class :

```
$('#id').on('mouseover',function(){
//addclass
}
```

then you remove the class of your div

```
$('#id').on('mouseout',function(){
//removeclass
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I do currently have:
`
$('.cbp-hrmenu').hover(function(){
    $('.menuDimmer').fadeIn(200);
},function(){
    $('.menuDimmer').fadeOut(50);
});
`

It does work but is a little messy as really only want to activate when the other element cbp-hropen is active.

Comment: @Gary like whats the problem? its to fast ?

Comment: The problem is that the style is applied when the user mouses over cbp-hrmenu, rather than the li inside it. I tried ('.cbp-hrmenu li').hover(function(), but it doesn't work at all (I'm probably structuring the part before the hover call wrong).

Comment: @Gary give an ID to your li and try it ?

Comment: OK, I gave the li an id of "menuHeader", and used the following:

$('#menuHeader').on('mouseover',function(){
    $('.menuDimmer').fadeIn(200);
} 
$('#menuHeader').on('mouseout',function(){
    $('.menuDimmer').fadeOut(50);
}

But still no joy!

Comment: @Gary still activating before li is hover?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MutationObserverAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)
to listen for DOM changes on specified elements. Take a look at the provided code in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49201984/9334163), as it shows how to use `MutationObserver` to detect class changes. The MDN doc linked above provides a more general example too.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a look!