# how to add style class to notion edit page

Tags: javascript, flutter, notion

I am trying to add some class style to notion edit page. But it seems that some kind of technologies(flutter-web?) notion used prevent that happens. the dom tree is rendered by a controlled  mutation state.

Any ideas that we can inject class to notion element?

below is the console warning when add class to notion page element:

```
4536-03e8b1b293f00187a4d8.js:1   NOTION WARNING  Reverting mutation of attribute class from "notion-selectable notion-text-block" -> "notion-selectable notion-text-block" in component undefined MutationRecord
```

Comment: Where is your code? How did you "add some class style"?

Comment: just simply element.classList.add("some-class")

Comment: I stil don't undertand why you need to do it, but now I can confirm: Notion does protect DOM against mutations using [MutationObserver class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) in code. See also [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201984/mutationobserver-class-changes)